# Hibernate Version Checking On Update Operation

Tags: hibernate

I read some articles about hibernate versioning:
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/transactions-optimistic.html
https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-version-property-hibernate/

and come up with new questions about it.

For example:

```
class Test {
   String name;
   int version;
}
```

For this Test class, on update operation. To check version, I can follow different strategies:

First one is I can manually check versions.

```
update(Test request) {
   Test exist = repository.find(...);
   if (exist.version != request.version) throw Exception();
   ...
}
```

Second one is I can directly send version to db and optimistic-lock handles it.

```
update(Test request) {
   Test exist = repository.find(...);
   exist.setName(request.name);
   exist.setVersion(request.version);
   repository.update(exist);
}
```

and if versions don't match, it throws `optimistic-lock-exception`.

When I think this case, first option looks like performant because detected problem before `db-call` but there is extra `if-control`. When I think an application, if there is `1M` request, optimistic lock problem might be `~%1` of requests so performance differences might be ignored.

What is your suggestion? Which one do you prefer or which one do you use on professional life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From JPA perspective you must perform version checking every time external data gets merged into persistent context, and I do see following three correct patterns there (all other patters are either the same or wrong):

1. external data is a DTO - we need to check version explicitly:

```java
void update(Dto dto) {
  // tx boundary start
  Entity e = em.find(EntityType.class, dto.getId());
  if (!Objects.equals(dto.getVersion(), e.getVersion())) {
   throw new VersionMismatchException();
  }
  copyData(Dto dto, Entity e);
  // tx boundary end
}
```

2. external data is a detached entity - we do not need to to anything but just call `EntityManager.merge()`, HBN will perform version checking by its own.

```java
void update(Entity detached) {
  // tx boundary start
  Entity e = em.merge(detached);
  // tx boundary end
}
```

3. external data is a detached entity, but instead of calling `EntityManager.merge()` we prefer to copy data on our own - in this case we need to check version explicitly as well as in DTO case.

```java
void update(Entity detached) {
  // tx boundary start
  Entity e = em.find(EntityType.class, detached.getId());
  if (!Objects.equals(detached.getVersion(), e.getVersion())) {
   throw new VersionMismatchException();
  }
  copyData(Entity detached, Entity e);
  // tx boundary end
}
```

From `spring-data-jpa` perspective we may reword previous "*you must perform version checking every time external data gets merged into persistent context*" as "**you must perform version checking every time external data crosses transaction boundary**", and the corresponding correct scenarios are following:

1. external data is a DTO - we need to check version explicitly:

```java
void update(Dto dto) {
  Entity e = repository.findById(dto.getId());
  if (!Objects.equals(dto.getVersion(), e.getVersion())) {
   throw new VersionMismatchException();
  }
  copyData(Dto dto, Entity e);
  repository.save(e);
}
```

2. external data is a detached entity - we do not need to to anything but just call `repository.save()`

```java
void update(Entity detached) {
  Entity e = repository.save(detached);
}
```

3. external data is a detached entity, but instead of calling `repository.save()` we prefer to copy data on our own - in this case we need to check version explicitly as well as in DTO case.

```java
void update(Entity detached) {
  Entity e = repository.findById(dto.getId());
  if (!Objects.equals(detached.getVersion(), e.getVersion())) {
   throw new VersionMismatchException();
  }
  copyData(Entity detached, Entity e);
  repository.save(e);
}
```

As regards to performance...

Optimistic locking is slow by design - you are forcing the client to retrieve actual version of data prior updating it, that looks natural for browser/user UI when users update what they see, however in case when our client is another system it might not look performant in some cases. In any case the attempt to measure performance in terms of the amount of `if` statements is definitely bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

#### How Hibernate handle optimistic-lock?

Let's see it on an example query.

```
Hibernate uses the version property in the WHERE clause of the executing UPDATE statement:

UPDATE
    test
SET
    name = :newName,
    version = :existVersion + 1
WHERE
    id = :id AND version = :existVersion
```

So, if `version = :existVersion` doesn't match, then a `StaleStateExcetion` is thrown, which will be wrapped in a JPA `OptimisticLockException` when bootstrapping Hibernate using JPA.

#### Example

Let's consider we have a entity like that:

```
class Test {
   Long id;
   String name;
   int version;
}
```

For this `Test` class, on update operation. To check version, we can follow different strategies:

1. we can manually check versions:

```
update(Test request) {
   Test exist = repository.findById(request.id);
   if (exist.version != request.version) throw Exception();
   ...
}
```

- `Pros` it looks performant because of no-extra-db-call
- `Cons` but extra `business-check` and extra `if-check`

2. we can directly send version to db and optimistic-lock handles it.

```
@Transactional
update(Test request) {
   Test exist = repository.findById(request.id);
   exist.setName(request.name);
   exist.setVersion(request.version);
   repository.update(exist); //redundant call
}
```

- **This doesn't work**. "Trying to set the version of an entity to a specific value is a mistake because the default optimistic locking mechanism does not take into consideration the version from the entity Java object but from the loading-time snapshot."
- if we don't use `Transaction`, it works but not practical.

3. secure-key and manual-update
   Let's assume, we have a version field in `UUID` format so in this case we couldn't benefit from hibernate `@Version` because hibernate supports only `int` and `timestamp` for version-field.

```
update(Test request) {
   Test exist = repository.findById(request.id);
   if (exist.version != request.version) throw Exception();
   exist.setVersion(new UUID...);
   repository.customUpdate(exist, request.version);
   ...
}
```

- `Cons` custom update-query for each entity. and manual version control.
- `Pros` it is secure but do we really need this security? it looks like over-engineering.

4. secure-key and version
   Let's assume, we have a secure-key field in `UUID` and hibernate version but request/response doesn't know version.

```
update(Test request) {
   Test exist = repository.findById(request.id);
   if (exist.secureKey != request.secureKey) throw Exception();
   exist.setSecureKey(new UUID...);
   repository.update(exist);
   ...
}
```

- `Cons` but extra `business-check` and extra `if-check`
- `Pros` it is secure but do we really need this security? it looks like over-engineering.

#### References

- https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/transactions-optimistic.html
- https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-version-property-hibernate/

Comment: I'm pretty sure your conclusions are wrong, that even stated in Vlad's blog: "Trying to set the version of an entity to a specific value is a mistake because the default optimistic locking mechanism does not take into consideration the version from the entity Java object but from the loading-time snapshot"

Comment: BTW, update-version doesn't work on `transactional`. If we don't use `transactional`, it works.